# ReactHook adding array of an array state without duplicating the key

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add data grouping by the unit name for showing functionality

```
const [allData , setAllData]= useState([{'unit':'' , data:[]}])   

 useEffect(async () => {
        await axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/data`).then(res => {
            res.data.map(elem => {
                setAllData(prev =>[...prev , { 'unit': elem.unitName, 'data': [elem.lessonName] }]);
            });
        });
    }, []);
```

the result is duplicating the key for the subarray which is "unit" for my exampl:

```
[
    {
        "unit": "unit 1",
        "data": [
            "LO1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "unit": "unit 2",
        "data": [
            "LO2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "unit": "unit 3",
        "data": [
            "LO3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "unit": "unit 1",
        "data": [
            "LO15"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: So does that mean you need to keep a **unique** `unit` value without considering the `data` ?

Comment: What is the expected output?...

Comment: I want to keep the "unit" value unique and checking every time if the unit existed then add more data to the same array of that unique key, so the result will look some thing like that:

[
    {
        "unit": "unit 1",
        "data": [
            "LO1" , "LO15"
        ]
    },
    {
        "unit": "unit 2",
        "data": [
            "LO2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "unit": "unit 3",
        "data": [
            "LO3"
        ]
    }
]

Comment: Would probably be easier to structure the state as key value pairs with the unit name as the key

Comment: @AsafAviv I tried it but I couldn't make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like that, if find unique property `unit` rewrite `data` or push new element to array

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    await axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/data`).then(res => {
        setAllData((prev) => {
          let result = [...prev];
          res.data.forEach(({ unitName: unit, lessonName }) => {
            const index = result.findIndex((elem) => elem.unit === unit);
            if (index >= 0) {
              result[index].data = [...result[index].data, lessonName]
            } else {
              result.push({unit, data: [lessonName]});
            }
          });
          return result;
        });
    });
  }, []);
```